# Query XML with variable using PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I've started parsing XML with PHP and got stuck with this problem. I've managed to query the XML with the following method:

```
echo $xml->textbox->item->id;
```

What's the syntax to use a variable instead of textbox?

I've tried (but didn't work):

```
echo $xml[$type]->item->id;
echo $xml->[$type]->item->id;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$xml->{$variable}->item->id
```

will work. You may want to check first whether  that path exists, e.g. using `empty()`.

Comment: thanks - this works!
i forgot to ask something else:
how to put the variable inside the for each loop?
foreach($xml as {$type]) doesnt work .. :(

Comment: @Fuxi to be honest, I'm not entirely sure: XML nodes have their own structure. Try to see what comes out of `foreach ($xml as $key => $value)` - see what $key and $value contain